# Проблемы с Random

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Есть проблема, написал телеграм бота( для своих одногрупников который делает предсказания что будет на паре )
Проблема: выдаёт сразу все предсказания( текст1, текст2, текст 3 ) я хочу чтобы было только одно предсказание, помогите решить
Вот код:

```
# Подключаем модуль случайных чисел
import random

# Подключаем модуль для Телеграма

import telebot

# Указываем токен

bot = telebot.TeleBot('тут ввёл токен, но спрятал его')

# Импортируем типы из модуля, чтобы создавать кнопки

from telebot import types

# Заготовки для трёх предложений

first = ["Текст 1","text2","text3"]

second = ["текст 2", "text_her","Segodnya budet horosho"]

second_add = ["текст 3","luboi text","text_text"]

third = ["текст 4","gggg","fdgdg"]

fourth = ["text 5","fsdfs","fsd"]

fifth = ["text 6","fsfsd","fsd"]

sixth = ["text 7","fsd","sdfsdf"]


# Метод, который получает сообщения и обрабатывает их

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    # Если написали «Привет»

    if message.text == "Привет":
        # Пишем приветствие

        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет, хочешь раскажу что будет сегодня на паре?")

        # Готовим кнопки

        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

        # По очереди готовим текст и обработчик для каждого знака зодиака

        key_oven = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Информатика', callback_data='zodiac')

        # И добавляем кнопку на экран

        keyboard.add(key_oven)

        key_telec = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Математика', callback_data='zodiac')

        keyboard.add(key_telec)

        key_bliznecy = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Биология', callback_data='zodiac')

        keyboard.add(key_bliznecy)

        key_rak = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='История', callback_data='zodiac')

        keyboard.add(key_rak)

        key_lev = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Труды', callback_data='zodiac')

        keyboard.add(key_lev)

        key_deva = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Физра', callback_data='zodiac')

        keyboard.add(key_deva)

        key_vesy = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='География', callback_data='zodiac')

        keyboard.add(key_vesy)

        key_scorpion = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Всемирная История', callback_data='zodiac')

        keyboard.add(key_scorpion)

        key_strelec = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='ЧКР', callback_data='zodiac')

        keyboard.add(key_strelec)

        key_kozerog = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Физика', callback_data='zodiac')

        keyboard.add(key_kozerog)

        key_vodoley = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Химия', callback_data='zodiac')

        keyboard.add(key_vodoley)

        key_ryby = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Английский', callback_data='zodiac')

        keyboard.add(key_ryby)

        # Показываем все кнопки сразу и пишем сообщение о выборе

        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text='Выбери свою пару:', reply_markup=keyboard)

    elif message.text == "/help":

        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Если не понимаешь что тут, просто напиши Привет")

    else:

        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, ".")


# Обработчик нажатий на кнопки

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    # Если нажали на одну из 12 кнопок — выводим гороскоп

    if call.data == "zodiac":
        # Формируем гороскоп

        msg = random.choice(first) + ' ' + random.choice(second) + ' ' + random.choice(second_add) + ' ' + random.choice(third) + ' ' + random.choice(fourth) + ' ' + random.choice(fifth) + ' ' + random.choice(sixth)

        # Отправляем текст в Телеграм

        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, msg)


# Запускаем постоянный опрос бота в Телеграме

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: уберите пустые строки, скроллить устает рука. И удалите все не относящееся к проблеме (выбор предмета, например).

Comment: В коде всё нормально с виду, подозреваю, что у вас запущен в боте не этот код